# Return type inference in a function according to input

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I want to define a function for base classes and get the right return type for calls with derived classes. E.g.

```
# Module 1:
from typing import TypeVar

class Food:
    pass

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, food: Food) -> None:
        self.food=food

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Food)
S = TypeVar("S", bound=Animal)

def get_food(animal: S) -> T:  # Illustrates what I want but not working.
    return animal.food

food = get_food(Animal(Food()))
reveal_type(food)  # Food.
```

```
# Module 2:
class Carrot(Food):
    pass

class Rabbit(Animal):
    def __init__(self, food: Carrot) -> None:
        self.food=food

food = get_food(Rabbit(Carrot()))
reveal_type(food)  # Food. Want Carrot.
```

The options I know are:

1. using the `@overload` decorator, but this means module 1 needs to be aware of the inheriting types in module 2 - which is a problem
2. have a new `get_food` in module 2 that delegates to module 1 and explicitly cast the return type:

```
def get_food(rabbit: Rabbit) -> Carrot:
    return cast(Carrot, get_food(rabbit))
```

Any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `Animal` class generic in food type. It means basically that any [non-strict] `Animal` subclass has some sort of food ([non-strict] subclass of `Food`) associated with it.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class Food:
    pass


_F = TypeVar("_F", bound=Food)


class Animal(Generic[_F]):
    def __init__(self, food: _F) -> None:
        self.food = food


def get_food(animal: Animal[_F]) -> _F:
    return animal.food


food = get_food(Animal(Food()))
reveal_type(food)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Food"


class Carrot(Food):
    pass

class Rabbit(Animal[Carrot]):
    pass


food = get_food(Rabbit(Carrot()))
reveal_type(food)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Carrot"
```

Here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=4a9edfca7bbdc6ab842efdc579e8f5a3) and a [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) on generic classes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my example wasn't close enough as my real "Animal" Doesn't store "Food" in it - I just have two classes that are sort of bonded somewhere in the hierarchy. But this is a good answer to this question :)